# How does the step-counter from the samsung health app, count the steps?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I know that when I want to use any of androids sensors, I have to register them and read their values via onSensorChanged().

If I am done with them, I unregister them to save power.

How come the step-counter in my Galaxy S7s health app is able to count steps?

I assume it's not e.g. the accelerometer, since the high power consumption of the sensor would drain my battery in hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really great article on this because I wondered the same a while back. 
https://www.explainthatstuff.com/how-pedometers-work.html

Here is the short version

Modern pedometers work in a very similar way but are partly electronic. Open one up and you'll find a metal pendulum (a hammer with a weight on one end) wired into an electronic counting circuit by a thin spring. Normally the circuit is open and no electric current flows through it. As you take a step, the hammer swings across and touches a metal contact in the center, completing the circuit and allowing current to flow. The flow of current energizes the circuit and adds one to your step count. As you complete the step, the hammer swings back again (helped by the spring) and the circuit is broken, effectively resetting the pedometer ready for the next step. The pedometer shows a count of your steps on an LCD display; most will convert the step count to an approximate distance in miles or kilometers (or the number of calories you've burned off) at the push of a button. Note that in some pedometers, the hammer-pendulum circuit works the opposite way: it's normally closed and each step makes it open temporarily.

More sophisticated pedometers (including some of the really good ones made by Omron) work entirely electronically and, since they have no moving parts, tend to be longer-lasting, more reliable, and considerably more accurate. They dispense with the swinging pendulum-hammer and measure your steps with two or three accelerometers instead. These are microchips arranged at right angles that detect minute changes in force as you move your legs. Since accelerometers are often built into gadgets like cellphones, it's increasingly common to find these sorts of things offering to count your steps for you too (there are plenty of pedometer apps for the iPhone, for example). GPS satellite navigation devices can also figure out how far you've walked or run, but they do it by calculating from satellite signals rather than counting steps

Answer (score 0):

Some sensors like the accelerometer, and light sensor are running at all times in a low power mode. The light sensor is running at all times to adjust the screen brightness according to ambient light, and the accelerometer is running at all times to detect the screen rotation. I suspect this low power mode has the sensors running at low frequencies to save battery.